# Generic return type of non-explicit generic type declared by wildcard

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Imagine this piece of code:

```
public static <T> T[] superClassArray(Class<? extends T[]> subClass) {
    T[] superArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(subClass.getComponentType().getSuperclass(), 0);
    return superArray;
}
```

The return type `T[]` of this method would be of whatever type was given as argument `subClass`, even thought `subClass`is not garanted to actually represent `T[]` but just a *subclass* (`? extends T`). So the actual return type should be `Object` since `T[]` is not declared more explicitly than being *any superclass* of `subclass`.
However,

```
Integer[] objA = superClassArray(Integer[].class);
```

compiles because it is erroneously expected to return a `Integer[]` object but obviously throws a `ClassCastException` because a `Number[]` object is actually returned.

So is there a justification for poor handling of generic types only declared through rather vague wildcards, or am *I* mistaken at any point of my consideration?

Comment: I seem to be missing something. Where's the "poor handling" except in your unsafe cast?

Comment: Why am I handling it poorly there exactly? I think my point got somehow burried in the elaboration of my question.
My point is, that `T[]` _itself_ is never declared explicitly, the only thing that is declared is `subClass` which only _extends_ `T[]`. However, the method's return type `T[]` is automatically assumed to be `subClass` _itself_ which is however not granted and also never 'stated' in the method call.

Comment: You made a dumb cast and got burned. You can't blame Java for that any more than you can blame it for letting wrong non-generic casts through. If you didn't make unsafe casts, you would have been fine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are not very consistent in what you are trying to do.
With your method you are creating an array of SUPERTYPE of your class, which actually succeds.

But then you are trying to assign it to a reference to a SUBTYPE which is illegal. If you are actually sure that this array cannot contain values of any other type than Integer you can explicitly cast it:

```
Integer[] objA = (Integer[]) superClassArray(Integer[].class);
```

BUT I don't see any value at all in a code like that and in the real world if you have a task that you are trying to solve with something like this, you sould really think about it a few more times and come up with a better solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to do any manual casting. Generics has to handle that during compile time. If you get compile time error, You better fix this instead of doing unsafe casting in your below code snippet.

```
T[] superArray = (T[])Array.newInstance(subClass.getComponentType().getSuperclass(), 0);
```