# Advantage of generic wildcard in java.util.Arrays.copyOf(U[], int, Class<? extends T[]>)

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I've been browsing in java native source and found a conspicuous use of generic wildcards in `java.util.Arrays.copyOf(U[], int, Class<? extends T[]>)`:

```
public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
        ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
        : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

I wonder what is the advantage of the generic wildcard `Class<? extends T[]>`, instead of just `Class<T[]>`, of parameter `newType`, since `T` itself is not declared  more explicitly anywhere else anyway.
Actually, I rather see a potential disadvantage that is questioned in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43298028/7353216).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a `Dog[]` and an `Animal[]`, and you want to copy your `Dog[]` into a `Animal[]`:

```
Dog[] dogArray = whatever;
Animal[] animalArray = whatever;
Animal[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(dogArray, dogArray.length, animalArray.getClass());
```

`animalArray.getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends Animal[]>`, so if the method took a `Class<T[]>` instead of `Class<? extends T[]>` (where `T` is `Animal`), we'd have to cast it.

---

Say you have to deal with [array covariance](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20array%20covariance). You still have a `Dog[]` and an `Animal[]`, except now your `Animal[]` might actually be a `Subclass[]` for any subclass `Subclass` of `Animal`. You want to copy your `Dog[]` into whatever kind of array your `Subclass[]` really is (maybe there's something in your class heirarchy between `Dog` and `Animal`, I dunno). That's still

```
Animal[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(dogArray, dogArray.length, animalArray.getClass());
```

but now `animalArray.getClass()` really isn't a `Class<Animal[]>`, and it would be outright wrong to perform a cast. Having `copyOf` take a `Class<? extends T[]>` is much safer.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I think I based my thoughts on a wrong assumption concerning generics in general: The type `T[]` is not determined by the type argument `newType` but by the type of the variable the method's return value is assiged to ('`copy`' in your case), isn't it? - If yes, why is `U` (in `<T, U>`) not declared as `<U extends T>` then?

Comment: @Reizo: No, it's determined by `newType`. The variable you assign it to has nothing to do with it. As for why it's not declared `U extends T`, it's because `U` doesn't have to extend `T`. For example, you might be taking an `Object[]` that only holds `Integer`s and copying it to an `Integer[]`.

Comment: "`tArray.getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends T[]>`" It would actually return a `Class<? extends Object[]>` as `Object[]` is the erasure of `T[]`

Comment: @user102008: ...crap, I think you're right. I forgot `getClass` takes the erasure there. Maybe I was thinking of `U` and `T` as concrete types when I was writing this or something. I think I'll need to revise it.

Comment: @user102008: I think I've fixed things.

Answer (score -1):

Is the same reason why this is allowed:

```
Object[] o = new Integer[1];
```

I guess, it is just to be back-compatible/consistent.

What if then I try to set the one position in that `o` array to an String? a run-time exception occurs :S

This is why naked arrays are kind of broken and you should try to only use them for private fields otherwise you might be better off just using Collections like `List<E>` instead.